# present and dismiss UIViewController with completion blocks - without protocols and delegates

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I would like to present an instance of `VC2` from an instance of `VC1` and pass it a completion block to be executed when the `VC2` dismisses itself. The passed completion block will be a method call on the `VC1` instance.

What would be the correct way of doing this?

While presenting VC2 from VC1 normally is:

```
    VC2 *vc2 = [[VC2 alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:vc2 animated:YES completion: nil];
```

and in VC2

```
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];
```

(ps normally I would dismiss VC2 like this in VC2 - ie call a VC1 methods declared in a protocol

```
  [self.delegate dismissVC2]; // basically meaning VC1 to dismiss VC2
```

...but I guess VC2 can dismiss itself too - however I am not sure this is ALWAYS ok.

While in the Apple docs, they still recommend delegation scheme - however self dismissing works too.

Could you comment on this as well?)

I would like to do sth like this in VC2:

```
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: passedBlockFromVC1];
```

And when presenting VC2 pass this `passedBlockFromVC1` somehow to VC2 - while containing a VC1 method.

What would be the correct way of doing this ?

In summary, I am looking for a solution to present VC2 from VC1 and when VC2 get's dismissed it calls a VC1 method at completion - all without the need to define a protocol or use a delegate (which I find quite cumbersome to some extend in this case - BUT extremely reliable)

**Is that possible and recommended?**

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible but you have to watch out for retain cycles. Remember that a block will capture any variables referenced within it including self. If VC1 keeps a strong reference to VC2 then be careful not to let the block have a strong reference to VC1 as well. If needed make a `__weak` reference to self outside the block and use that.

[See the Apple Documentation for more information about retain cycles using blocks and how to avoid them.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW16)

The easiest thing to do would be to subclass UIViewController and make your own methods and properties to achieve this.

You can declare a property to store a block as an instance variable like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) dispatch_block_t completionBlock;
```

using the standard libdispatch block type.

Then define some methods for setting this up:

```
-(void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(void))completion dismissCompletion:(dispatch_block_t)dismissCompletion{
    self.completionBlock = dismissCompletion;
    [super presentViewController:viewController animated:animated completion:completion];
}
```

then override the dismiss method to call the completion block if there is one.

```
-(void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion{
    if (self.completionBlock && ! completion){
        [super dismissViewControllerAnimated:flag completion:self.completionBlock];
        self.completionBlock = nil;
        return;
    }
    [super dismissViewControllerAnimated:flag completion:completion];
}
```

Comment: wow - that looks quite nice and easy to do. Since it follows the scheme (as I was looking for) that VC2 dismisses itself (as opposed to through a delegate VC1) - do you know by any chance if using this does have any disadvantages over following Apple's recommended delegate way? This looks much more straight forward, is more flexible and easier to code - why would Apple not even mention sth like this as a valid alternative ?

Comment: Possibly because, if you're not aware of what you're doing its very very easy to get a retain cycle. Possibly because delegation is the normal pattern here and others can understand your code quicker. Maybe because if it ain't broke don't fix it? Also perhaps VC2 might want to perform different completion implementations depending on user input or something. If it works for you and you're aware of the limitations then do it if you want to.

Comment: Perfect thanks - I will start to use this as my "standard" - this avoids the creation of protocols AND delegates - while I think it is easier to read and understand since it's all in one place.

Comment: Hi guys, I know it is old. But the way you use is just something I was looking for. Could you maybe give some more info on where I declare these methods and properties? Because I cannot quite get it to work. Do I declare them in VC1 or VC2? And how do I call the new presentViewController method? Million thanks.

Comment: all goes in VC2. Then you call `-(void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(void))completion dismissCompletion:(dispatch_block_t)dismissCompletion` from VC1. Again, beware of the limitations is really easy to make a retain cycle

Comment: @jackslash Thanks, but how do I call the new function then? It does not exists in the presenting viewcontroller so it will fail. Or do I not call it with self but something different? Sorry for the troubles but this whole block stuff is pretty new to me.