# presentViewController with dismiss block

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

This is what I would like.
Present a UIViewController (UITableViewController) and in the presentViewController method incorporate a dismiss block.

So something like this:

```
[self presentViewController:vc 
    animated:YES 
    completion:nil 
    onDismiss:^{
        NSLog(@"dismissed")
    }
];
```

I tried implementing [This SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658147/present-and-dismiss-uiviewcontroller-with-completion-blocks-without-protocols) because it looks like the exact thing of what I need but didn't quite figure out how it should be done. Anyone that can provide me with a detailed description?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the gist of your code, that example looks like it should work fine.

Comment: I know. But I do not exactly know how I should fire the new presentViewController method. As it is defined in the new VC. It is not recognized by the presenting view controller.

Comment: Ah, the function definition jackslash provided should be defined in your special VC's header `-(void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(void))completion dismissCompletion:(dispatch_block_t)dismissCompletion` (and implemented in its implementation) then you call that function from the calling VC.

Comment: but I can not call it with [self .....]... and if I call it with [vc ....] (where it does recognize the method) the app crashes because I can not let a view controller present itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clarify the discussion in the comments:

In your ContainerViewController's header define this function:

```
-(void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(void))completion dismissCompletion:(dispatch_block_t)dismissCompletion
```

and follow the rest of the instructions for the implementation of the function for ContainerViewController from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12662872/155513)

Then in your ViewController call

```
[containerViewController presentViewController:presentedViewController animated:YES completion:<whatever> dismissCompletion:<whatever>]
```

If you're calling this from within a ContainerViewController you can call it on `self` if you're in SomeOtherViewController with a ContainerViewController (CVC) object call it on the CVC object.