# iOS - delegate not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have two view controllers, `AbcViewController` and `XyzViewController`. Both controllers behave similarly. Each has a "add" button which opens up a `AddNewAbcViewController` and `AddNewXyzViewController` respectively.

On `AddNewAbcViewController`, when the button "submit" is taped, it does it necessary stuff and close, bringing it back to `AbcViewController`. I am using delegate here where `AbcViewController` does the closing of `AddNewAbcViewController`. This works.

Now I want to do the same for `XyzViewController` and `AddNewXyzViewController`, but it is not working. When the btnSubmit is called in `AddNewXyzViewController`, it didn't enter into `XyzViewController` dimiss method. I have scanned through my codes many times but don't find anything extra not added. I even gave a different dismiss method name in `XyzViewController` and `AddNewXyzViewController` but that didn't work either. What did I miss?

here are my snippets for `AbcViewController` and `AddAbcViewController`. The codes for Xyz are identical:

class `AddNewAbcViewController.h` is

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// protocol
@protocol AddNewAbcProtocol <NSObject>

-(void)dismiss;

@end

@interface AddNewAbcViewController : UIViewController<UITextViewDelegate>

@property(nonatomic, weak)id<AddNewAbcProtocol> delegate;

@end
```

class `AddNewAbcViewController.m` is

```
@interface AddNewAbcViewController() <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
...
@end

@implementation AddNewAbcViewController

...

- (IBAction)btnSubmit:(id)sender
{
  [self.delegate dismiss];
}
@end
```

class `AbcViewController.h` is

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AddNewAbcViewController.h"

@interface AbcViewController : UIViewController<AddNewAbcProtocol, UISplitViewControllerDelegate>
...
@end
```

class `AbcViewController.m` is

```
@implementation AbcViewController

-(void)dismiss
{
    NSLog(@"delegated to dismiss()");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Comment: You haven't shown where you are setting the `delegate`

Comment: sorry setting delegate in where?

Comment: Also if you only want to dismiss the view controller you can use `[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];`

Comment: in AddNewAbcViewController you are calling `self.delegate dismiss` in order for that to work the `delegate` actually needs to be assigned. I'm assuming from `AbcViewController`. But as @Cornelius has said if all you are trying to do is dismiss it there are better ways

Comment: oh yes @Cornelius  but i need to refresh the tableview in AbcViewController.m

Comment: You can do that in the completion block (I NULL'ed it in my example, but you can call a block there that refreshes your tableview)

Comment: @Cornelius so in the completion block i can call a AbcViewController's method that refresh the table?

Comment: @Flexicoder, do you mean in AbcViewController init(), I add self.newAbc = [[AddNewAbcViewController alloc] init]; self.newAbc.delegate = self; ?????

Comment: @nuttynibbles I thought so, but sadly it isn't that easy. Look at this answer to see how it can be done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658147/present-and-dismiss-uiviewcontroller-with-completion-blocks-without-protocols/12662872#12662872

Maybe your delegate is the cleanest method, though ..

Comment: ya it does look complicated haha

Comment: @Flexicoder i managed to find the missing code. Tks alot mate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As everyone explained, basically you forgot a line of code like ".delegate = self".

Here's a handy beginner's intro to delegates.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4213005/294884

Comment: oh i just saw that piece of code in AbcViewController but not XyzViewController. thanks @Joe.

Comment: sorry it just happen not too long ago before i saw this

Comment: basically i forgot to set .delegate=self XyzViewController. Now that I've added, it works

Comment: ohh that green tick. sorry i always forgot to do so. now i know why i'm getting down vote haha

Answer (score 0):

Use if statement to see if delegate works:

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(dismiss)])
{
    [self.delegate dismiss];
}
```

Create AddNewXyzViewController as an instance variable, but not a local variable.

Comment: hello. i figure the problem was i didn't set .delegate=self. anw tks for the snippets.